# C# Selenium Element Finding problem using xpath

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

Here's the code, I am trying to locate the first email input box.
But I can't locate using the code below.

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.nike.com/register");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/form/div[1]/input"));
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Why aren't you using the input's ID or name? If the form's layout changes, your code will break

Comment: Yes, using input's type/placeholder will solve the problem. Basically using unique components

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution to this.

In chrome, when you are trying to inspect the elements of the page, the XPath you copied from the element is based on the first indicator. In this example, it is Id.

So I tried to use the Full XPath to locate the input box and it apparently doesn't work with C# selenium. (There could be other ways around this.)

(I used to write selenium with python and it does work when you are using Full XPath.)

**In this case, I ended up solving the problem by using the second indicator of the XPath. (type = "email") Just make sure it is unique to the element you are trying to locate you should be fine.**